# feh ERROR: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?

Tags: x11, raspberry-pi, raspbian, feh

Followed this tutorial to try and get a photo album running on my raspberry pi 3: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-photo-frame/

Using feh to try and run `DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority /usr/bin/feh --quiet --preload --randomize --full-screen --reload 60 -Y --slideshow-delay 15.0 /home/pi/Photos-001/`

But keep getting the error `feh ERROR: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?`.

I've tried `export DISPLAY=:0` but that doesn't seem to have any affect

Open to any solutions, or alternatives to feh

Running on Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) on a Raspberry Pi 3

Comment: Well, are you in X/GUI environment anyway? What's the output of `printenv DISPLAY` if you do not `export` any? (Normally you don't need to specify `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` unless you are e.g. trying to start a GUI app from ssh.)